# Curl In Codeigniter - Error Code 22, HTTP GET

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3

I want to fetch data from Third_party API called BirdEye. I was using Core PHP Inbuilt Functions of CURL to fetch data, it was working fine, Now When I switched to Library I am bit confused because it doesn't gives me any response in return.

I have Downloaded Curl Libray from Here : [Curl Library Download and Example](https://www.formget.com/curl-library-codeigniter/)

I tried to create a demo just to check my Library is working fine or not, it worked. Now If I fetch data from Bird-Eye Api I don't know It gives me nothing in response.
My Code is here:

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('curl');
        $get_url = "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/147802929307762?api_key=ApiKeyGoesHere";
        echo $this->curl->simple_get($get_url, false, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => true));
        echo $this->curl->error_code;
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong I am passing all the required parameters to the Api and when I try to echo error code it gives me 22. I even searched on birdeye documentation but nothing found.
Link to Api Documentation is : [Link to BirdEye Api Documentation](http://docs.birdeye.apiary.io/#reference/business/get/get-business)

Comment: I'm not gonna download the Curl Library so post in the question the source code for the simple_get function please.

Comment: it's of 400 lines Let me give u direct view of the file where you can view the file  https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl/blob/master/libraries/Curl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to the BirdEye API your cURL script should be like the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/businessId ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  "Content-Type: application/json",
  "Accept: application/json"
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Now, when I'm comparing your library usage code to the example above, I see you're missing the definitions of several options.

Before adding those options to your code, try to follow this part:

In the example they're not using the APIKEY, but when you do use it, you might need to pass it as a parameter and not in the get_url variable.
Which means:

```
 $get_url = "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/147802929307762";
        echo $this->curl->simple_get($get_url, array('api_key' => 'YourApiKeyGoesHere'), array(..));
```

If it still doesn't work, try to add the options to your code:

```
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $get_url = "https://api.birdeye.com/resources/v1/business/147802929307762?api_key=ApiKeyGoesHere";
    echo $this->curl->simple_get($get_url, false, array(CURLOPT_USERAGENT => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, CURLOPT_HEADER => FALSE, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json")));


    echo $this->curl->error_code;
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
```

Comment: Done ! But one more thing I am using Library Yet I have to pass header and other paramters?

Comment: Do you mean it works? I'm not familiar with Library Yet